# iOS native app build with phonegap opens in lower resolution

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, native, phonegap-build

When I open my application in the browser of my iPad Pro 12.9in while serving it with the PhoneGap app on my desktop, it opens as it should. But when I install the application and open it, it opens with a lower resolution. I saw this could be because of lower resolutions spash screens but I designed a new splashscreen with resolution 2732x2048 for the iPad pro.

Should I maybe change something in the config.xml file? I have tried a lot but still haven't found a solution.

[These are the imported splash images for iOS with their resolutions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2K81.png)

[This is how the app looks when installed (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Inu8.jpg)

[This is how the app looks when installed (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI74M.jpg)

[This is how the app should look - like it is now in the browser (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GLjia.jpg)

[This is how the app should look - like it is now in the browser (2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNnOC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you added your new Splashscreen to your config.xml?

You need the following entries in that file:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    <splash src="<your path>/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="<your path>/Default@2x~universal~comany.png" />
    <splash src="<your path>/Default@2x~universal~comcom.png" />
    <splash src="<your path>/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="<your path>/Default@3x~universal~anycom.png" />
    <splash src="<your path>/Default@3x~universal~comany.png" />
</platform>
```

In my case path is `<project>/res/ios`

For using these, you need at least CLI 7.0.1 or 7.1.0 to target iOS Phonegap Version 4.4.0

Additional information:

- https://medium.com/@photokandy/phonegap-build-supports-ios-launch-storyboards-44a4180bfafe
- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/
- https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2251428

Comment: Ok so I adjusted my config.xml to use storyboard images and no legacy launch images but now the logo is shown as splash image. I am using PhoneGap CLI 6.5.0 and iOS Phonegap Version 4.3.1. In my xml file I have also imported the cordova-plugin-splashscreen version 3.2.1:
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" spec="~3.2.1" />

Comment: Can you give it a try by targeting a higher version like CLI 7.0.1 or 7.1.0? For me it worked with 6.5.0 but I found an post that mentioned that this requires 4.4.0. Is there a reason why u are using an old version of the splashscreen plugin? Latest version is 5.0.2. Take a look: https://medium.com/@photokandy/phonegap-build-supports-ios-launch-storyboards-44a4180bfafe

Comment: Thanks! Upgrading to CLI 8.0.0 worked for me but then I ran into some building errors. All is fixed now and works like it should be.